# PyQt5: count seconds mouse is over QPushButton in tooltip

Tags: python-3.x, events, pyqt5, tooltip, qpushbutton

The following running code gives a window with a button on it . The tooltip displays when the mouse enters the button.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("MyButton")
        
        global i
        i = 0

        self.button.setToolTip(str(i) + " seconds has passed since you move your mouse onto MyButton")
        self.button.leaveEvent = self.clear()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.start_counting)
        timer.start(1000)
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
    
    def clear(self):
        global i
        i = 0
        
    def start_counting(self):
        if self.button.underMouse() == True:
            global i
            i = i + 1
            self.button.setToolTip(str(i) + " seconds has passed since you move your mouse onto MyButton")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

My goal is to count the number of seconds the mouse is inside the button and live display it using the tooltip. More precisely, I need to make sure all of the following is happening:

1. Every time the mouse enters the button, the count starts at 0 seconds and the tooltip shows up.
2. While the mouse stays inside the button (stationary or moving), the tooltip stays shown with the number of seconds (the text displayed inside the tooltip) updated over time.
3. When the mouse leaves the button, the count is cleared to zero.

---

As seen in the code, I have attempted to use `underMouse` to achieve my goals. My attempt is a partial success as the tooltip does update itself when the mouse moves inside the button. However, the tooltip does not update itself when the mouse stays stationary inside the button. Also, the count does not seem to be cleared when the mouse moves outside of the button .

What am I missing ?

Comment: First of all, don't use globals. Then, `self.clear()` returns `None`, so you're actually doing `self.button.leaveEvent = None`. Besides, just add an `else` in `start_counting` and reset the counter. Then, use the [static functions of QToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText).

Comment: The thing is, I cannot access the `QToolTip` object. `self.button.toolTip()` only returns a string and not an object of type `QToolTip`. I also tried to create my own object of type `QToolTip` by writing `self.tool_tip = QToolTip()`. It gives an error of not enough arguments although the documentation says I don't need any. I really need more guidance on the subject.

Comment: No, you don't have access to the QToolTip class doesn't represent the actual "widget", but it's an interface to access it. That's why you have to use the static functions as I wrote above.

Comment: I am still not sure about what you mean. I tried things in the form `QToolTip.showText(self.button.pos(),"TEXT", self.button )` and several other things in the past few hours. None of which seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use an [event-filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) to monitor the enter and leave events, and also use an [elapsed-timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html) to get an accurate measure of how long the mouse has been over the target widget. Below is a basic demo based on your example that implements the above. It also tries to match the normal behaviour of tooltips, but if necessary you can easily adjust the code to suit your own needs:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("MyButton")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.position = QPoint()
        self.counter = QElapsedTimer()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.start_counting)
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter and source is self.button:
            self.counter.start()
            self.timer.start(1000)
            QTimer.singleShot(500, self.start_counting)
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave and source is self.button:
            self.timer.stop()
            QToolTip.hideText()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def start_counting(self):
        if self.button.underMouse():
            if not QToolTip.isVisible():
                self.position = QCursor.pos()
            count = int(self.counter.elapsed() / 1000)
            QToolTip.showText(self.position, (
                f'{count} seconds have passed since '
                'you moved your mouse onto MyButton'
                ))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```